# Passing "struct sockaddr_in" to a method

Tags: c, linux, sockets

How can I pass `struct sockaddr_in z` to a my method?

```
void method(?);

int main(void){
struct sockaddr_in z;
...
}

void method(?){
....
}
```

What goes in place of "?"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

With a pointer, like this:

```
void method(struct sockaddr_in *z);

int main(void){
    struct sockaddr_in z;
    z.sin_port = 4242;
    method(&z);
}

void method(struct sockaddr_in *z){
    printf("%i\n", z->sin_port);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you the last think? When I compile the code I obtain this error: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token.          This is because I pass other parameters:                           void method(s,file_config,server,porta,&z); How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: You are missing to initialise `z`, so accessing it leads to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it's just an example but it's right I will edit my answer thanks

Comment: If `method()` only needs to read from `z`, it should be  `const`.

Comment: We don't know what `method()` does, stop guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a `struct` by value is perfectly legal in C:

```
void func(struct sockaddr_in z);

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in z = {0};

    func(z);
}

void func(struct sockaddr_in z)
{
    printf("%d\n", z.sin_port);
}
```